# box.com node client - cannot access files created by collaborator

Tags: node.js, box

1. I'm the co-owner on a box.com file.
2. My boss is the owner.
3. I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/box-node-sdk to manage the files
4. The node client has my bosses' enterprise credentials
5. He made a folder
6. I made several other sibling folders
7. I can retreive his
8. I can't retreive mine
9. We're both listed as collaborators on all the files

The error I get looks like this:

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "response": {
    "statusCode": 404,
    "body": {
      "type": "error",
      "status": 404,
      "code": "not_found",
      "context_info": {
        "errors": [
          {
            "reason": "invalid_parameter",
            "name": "item",
            "message": "Invalid value 'd_11786923812'. 'item' with value 'd_11786923812' not found"
          }
        ]
      },
      "help_url": "http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors",
      "message": "Not Found",
      "request_id": "338009555580a32f872f7c"
    },
    "headers": {
      "server": "ATS",
      "date": "Fri, 21 Oct 2016 15:23:36 GMT",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "content-length": "324",
      "cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
      "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
      "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
      "age": "0",
      "connection": "keep-alive"
    },
    "request": {
      "uri": {
        "protocol": "https:",
        "slashes": true,
        "auth": null,
        "host": "api.box.com",
        "port": 443,
        "hostname": "api.box.com",
        "hash": null,
        "search": null,
        "query": null,
        "pathname": "/2.0/folders/11786923812",
        "path": "/2.0/folders/11786923812",
        "href": "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/11786923812"
      },
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "Box Node.js SDK v1.1.0",
        "Authorization": "[REMOVED BY SDK]",
        "accept": "application/json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: So, I can get folder 0 and it's not where I'm looking BUT, I did check earlier and added a file where I thought I was looking and it did show up, so I'm guessing that my boss would have to create the files...

Comment: The error suggests the document (11786923812) you're trying to access doesn't exist. Can you verify that it does?

Comment: @LarryTurtis Yes it does. I think I've worked this one out. The enterprise account belongs to him and the client we create has him as a user. I think unless he creates the files directly he can't see them...